# How to make a split archive for DVD storage where single files are extracted from the set without needing all the DVD's

Tags: windows, 7-zip

I'm getting ready to 7z/rar/whatever 1125 files (About 300GB) into a split archive with each piece being 4,700,372,992 bytes. The idea is that I can put each split onto a DVD+R that will fill the DVD right to the last byte.

Now with my problem. Back in the day, I could use zip to make a multi-part archive that contained the whole TOC of the archive in the last file. For some reason, this convenience has either been lost or buried. I need this function since I will probably only extract one file from the archive when I want it. Putting in 70 DVD's for one file would be ridicules. In 7-zips case, I'd have to copy all the DVD's to the HDD to even look at the archive. In RAR I don't have an index I can call up to tell my which DVD the file is on.

Now my question is, is there a way to make a split archive that will allow me to load either the first or last file in the split without the other split files being present (on the DVD to be exact) and when I select which file to extract, it will tell me which split file I need.

I'm considering using WinArchiver's mzp format, but I can't get it to just store files (it wants to compress them no matter what) since the files in question are packed with 7z which is hard to beat compression wise.